# Изменить формат вывода по regex

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет, еще только изучаю язык, строго не судите
такой вопрос: все номера телефонов в тексте записанные в формате +375XXYYYYYYY с помощью regex заменить на +375(XX)YYY-YY-YY 
саму регулярку написать проблем нет, вопрос как заменить. matcher.replaceAll очевидно не работает по такому принципу

```
    package Regex;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Phone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[+]375(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})");
        String str = "+12315125 +375442345295 1235 +375257621398 ";
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
    //???
            System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll([+]375\((\d{2})\)(\d{3})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2}));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
String s = "+375125522214 +12315125 +375442345295 1235 +375257621398";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\+375(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})","+375($1)$2-$3-$4"));
```

Вывод: `+375(12)552-22-14 +12315125 +375(44)234-52-95 1235 +375(25)762-13-98`.

Через `Matcher` и `Pattern` тоже можно:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[+]375(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})");
String str = "+375125522214 +12315125 +375442345295 1235 +375257621398";
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("+375($1)$2-$3-$4"));
```

Вывод: `+375(12)552-22-14 +12315125 +375(44)234-52-95 1235 +375(25)762-13-98`.

Через `$1` указывается ссылка на первую группу (выражение в скобках), выражение из этой группы подставляется на место `$1`.

Comment: Дефисы потеряли `+375(XX)YYY-YY-YY`

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Ну вот теперь держите плюсик :)

Comment: Спасибо большое)